# upon npm start I just have a blank screen. What can I do to get things to render?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, chakra-ui

I ironed out any error messages that were popping up and the code still isn't rendering. I'm dumb and not that great at React or version control yet.

app.js file

```jsx
import './App.css';
import Header from "./Header";
import Main from "./Main";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import { Grid, GridItem } from "@chakra-ui/react";

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)" gap={4}>
      <GridItem colSpan={3}>
        <Header />
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>
        <Nav />
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem colSpan={2}>
        <Main />
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem colSpan={3}>
        <Footer />
      </GridItem>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried playing with the names of components, I was expecting some routing maybe to get fixed and the whole thing will render? obviously I'm clueless...

Comment: A blank browser page is usually accompanied by errors reported in the dev-tools console. Are there any?

Comment: I looked but literally the whole dev tools is blank, elements, console etc

Comment: To be clear I didn't see any in Vs code console or dev tools..no errors....

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to guess without seeing actual error message.
I suspect you might forgot [to wrap](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started) entire `App` to `<ChakraProvider/>`. Like so:

```
import './App.css';
import Header from "./Header";
import Main from "./Main";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import { Grid, GridItem, ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)" gap={4}>
        <GridItem colSpan={3}>
          <Header />
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem>
          <Nav />
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem colSpan={2}>
          <Main />
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem colSpan={3}>
          <Footer />
        </GridItem>
      </Grid>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also, make sure you have installed all required npm dependencies

```bash
npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled framer-motion
```